# Why am I unable to deploy this maven application due to a PersistenceException?

Tags: java, hibernate, maven, wildfly-10

I am trying to deploy my maven web application in Jboss wildfly 10 with properties

```
<properties>            
<property name="hibernate.dialect"
value="org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect" />
<property    name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update" /> 
<property    name="hibernate.show_sql" value="false" /> 
<property    name="hibernate.format_sql" value="false" />           
<property    name="hibernate.temp.use_jdbc_metadata_defaults" value="false"/>
 </properties>
```

then i am getting the following error

```
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: process-PU] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.persistenceException(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:954)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:882)
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.hibernate5.TwoPhaseBootstrapImpl.__build(TwoPhaseBootstrapImpl.java:44)
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.hibernate5.TwoPhaseBootstrapImpl.build(TwoPhaseBootstrapImpl.java)
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl$1$1.run(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:154)
    ... 7 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.tool.schema.extract.spi.SchemaExtractionException: More than one table found in namespace (, ) : Table_name
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.extract.internal.InformationExtractorJdbcDatabaseMetaDataImpl.processGetTableResults(InformationExtractorJdbcDatabaseMetaDataImpl.java:381)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.extract.internal.InformationExtractorJdbcDatabaseMetaDataImpl.getTable(InformationExtractorJdbcDatabaseMetaDataImpl.java:279)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.extract.internal.DatabaseInformationImpl.getTableInformation(DatabaseInformationImpl.java:105)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaMigratorImpl.doMigrationToTargets(SchemaMigratorImpl.java:162)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaMigratorImpl.doMigration(SchemaMigratorImpl.java:60)
    at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate.execute(SchemaUpdate.java:133)
    at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate.execute(SchemaUpdate.java:101)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:470)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.__build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:444)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:879)
```

Comment: `SchemaExtractionException` is your cause to this problem try search for it

Comment: Thanx for the reply but its working fine with jboss 7.2.0

Comment: Hibernate 5 is in wildfly 10 but 4.x in 7.2.0. That might be the the reason. I too facing this issue after changing to 10.